# How can I lock CPU frequency in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: power-management, cpu, cpufreq

It's a Server (Dell PowerEdge R730xd)

The CPU is Intel Xeon E5 2630 v4 2.2GHz

The OS and kernel is Ubuntu 16.04 and 4.15.0-33-generic

The current settings are as follows:

1. intel_pstate is disabled

> Add "intel_pstate=disable" to /etc/default/grub
>
> cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver will show ***acpi-cpufreq***

2. Use ***userspace governor***

> sudo cpupower frequency-set -g userspace
>
> cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor will show ***userspace***

3. Set a target frequency

> sudo cpupower frequency-set -f 2.2G
>
> cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq will show ***2200000***

**However**, by using *watch -n 1 "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz"* to monitor the current CPU frequency, I find that the frequency is always changing. (Using i7z is the same)

Only when the load becomes higher (e.g., use ***stress -c 40***) the CPU frequency will remaine stable in 2.2GHz.

> The current BIOS power management settings are as follows:
>
> - CPU Power Management -> OS DBPM (i.e., OS Control)
> - Memory Frequency -> Maximum Performance
> - Turbo Boost -> Disabled
> - C1E -> Disabled (When set to Enabled, the processor is allowed to switch to minimum performance state when idle)
> - C States -> Disabled (C States allow the processor to enter lower power states when idle)
> - Collaborative CPU Performace Control -> Enabled
> - Uncore Frequency -> Maximum
> - Energy Efficient Policy -> Performance (And there are other options, e.g., *Balanced Performance / Balanced Energy / Energy Efficient*）
> - Monitor/Mwait -> Enabled

So, how can I lock my CPU frequency?! Many thanks!

Comment: The problem has been solved. By adding "idle = poll" to grub to disable C state.

Comment: What was the goal of this? Increase power consumption? The Kernel/CPU are trying to save power by not running at maximum speed when not needed. As you point out, when there's an actual load it will go into the highest power state. If you're on processors that can turbo (you disabled it in BIOS, but not sure if Xeons can anyway), it may actually harm performance as the CPU would want to power-off idle cores and turbo the active ones to a higher frequency. Benchmarking software is the only reason I can think of...